# Is there a way to use a Teams Canned Response on DMs?

Tags: microsoft-teams

This may not be the correct place for this but...

Is there a way to save Canned responses for Teams?

I'm not looking for an automatic reply, but to use whenever I introduce myself on DMs

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your requirement and share the repro steps?

Comment: So I'm primarily looking on client side.  So when I right click chat > open new chat > look at the array of icons below the Message box, I'm looking to click on a button to autofill the box and then edit as needed.  Also to have the ability to create other autofills

Comment: This is more of a feature request, could you please raise your voice here: 
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new

Comment: Great, that's definitely what I'm looking for.  Thanks!